# No data returned from useQuery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-query

i am new to react query
i did not get any data return by useQuery hook but api request is working fine

```jsx
const listofgroupsapi = async (lastId, limit, id) => {
  const res = await axios.get(
    `${apiURL}/groups/getAllGroups?lastId=-1&limit=10&id=${id}`
  );
  console.log(res.data);
  return res.data;
};

const Superadminpanel = () => {
const [lastId, setLastId] = useState(0);
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(10);
  const [id, setId] = useState(cookies.id);
  const { isLoading, data } = useQuery("groups", () => {
    listofgroupsapi(lastId, limit, id);
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ minHeight: "90vh" }}>
      <div>
        <h1>here we are</h1>
        {isLoading ? <h1>loading</h1> : <h1>not loading</h1>}
        {data ? <h1>data</h1> : <h1>no data:{data}</h1>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Superadminpanel;
```

console.log(res.data) gives me correct result from my api

[response of my api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QskgQ.png)

I don't know why `useQuery` doesn't give me any data

[React query dev tool image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFBHd.png)

Comment: Where are `lastId`, `limit` and `id` supposed to come from?

Comment: those are useState

Comment: They should be part of the `useQuery()` [query key](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/query-keys#if-your-query-function-depends-on-a-variable-include-it-in-your-query-key)

Comment: error is not because of that if i remove those params and give hardcoded value. still useQuery does not return any thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you aren't returning the promise result from `listofgroupsapi()` but there are also other improvements you can make.

As per the [react-query documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/query-keys#if-your-query-function-depends-on-a-variable-include-it-in-your-query-key)...

> **If your query function depends on a variable, include it in your query key**
>
> Since query keys uniquely describe the data they are fetching, they should include any variables you use in your query function that **change**

With that in mind, you should use the following

```js
const listofgroupsapi = async (lastId, limit, id) =>
  (
    await axios.get(`/groups/getAllGroups`, { // no need for template literals
      baseURL: apiURL,
      params: { // query params are easier and safer this way
        lastId: -1, // not lastId?
        limit: 10, // not limit?
        id,
      },
    })
  ).data;
```

and in your component

```js
const { isLoading, data } = useQuery(["groups", lastId, limit, id], () =>
  listofgroupsapi(lastId, limit, id) // no {...} means implicit return
);
```